# Agrupamento em objetos dinamicos

Tags: jquery

Meu php esta retornando estes dados:

```
 {"question":"Name","answer":"jorge","qt":"1","graph":"table"}
            {"pergunta":"Name","answer":"Jorge","qt":"2","graph":"table"}
            {"question":"Name","answer":"Jhon","qt":"1","graph":"table"}
            {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"red","qt":"1","graph":"column"}
            {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"blue","qt":"1","graph":"column"}
            {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"yellow","qt":"1","graph":"column"}
            {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"No","qt":"1","graph":"pie"}
            {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"Yes","qt":"3","graph":"pie"}
```

Este seria o retorno em jquery que preciso fazer dinamicamente pois haverá momentos que terei mais perguntas que este exemplo.
Então preciso agrupar as perguntas iguais em objetos pois cada objeto alimentara um gráfico em canvas js.

```
{data : [{"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"No","qt":"1","graph":"pie"},
    {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"Yes","qt":"3","graph":"pie"}]}

    {data :[{"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"red","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
    {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"blue","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
    {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"yellow","qt":"1","graph":"column"}]}

    {data :[{"question":"Name","answer":"jorge","qt":"1","graph":"table"},
    {"question":"Name","answer":"Jorge","qt":"2","graph":"table"},
    {"question":"Name","answer":"Jhon","qt":"1","graph":"table"}]}
```

Alguma idéia de como fazer isso?
Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em sua pergunta não identificou o retorno do Php como um array com a presença de '[]' e separação dos itens com ',' então Considere o seu PHP retornar um array dos objetos citados na pergunta, por exemplo:

```
var retornoPHP = [{"question":"Name","answer":"jorge","qt":"1","graph":"table"},
     {"question":"Name","answer":"Jorge","qt":"2","graph":"table"},
     {"question":"Name","answer":"Jhon","qt":"1","graph":"table"},
     {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"red","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
     {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"blue","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
     {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"yellow","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
     {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"No","qt":"1","graph":"pie"},
     {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"Yes","qt":"3","graph":"pie"}];
```

e então faça:

```js
var retornoPhp = [{"question":"Name","answer":"jorge","qt":"1","graph":"table"},
         {"question":"Name","answer":"Jorge","qt":"2","graph":"table"},
         {"question":"Name","answer":"Jhon","qt":"1","graph":"table"},
         {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"red","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
         {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"blue","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
         {"question":"what is your favorite color ?","answer":"yellow","qt":"1","graph":"column"},
         {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"No","qt":"1","graph":"pie"},
         {"question":"Are you over 20 years old?","answer":"Yes","qt":"3","graph":"pie"}];

 var arrayAgrupado = retornoPhp.reduce(function(ant, atu){ 
  if(ant.length > 0 && ant[ant.length - 1].data.length > 0 && ant[ant.length - 1].data[0].question == atu.question) { 
   ant[ant.length - 1].data.push(atu);
   return ant;
  } else {
   return ant.concat([{data: [atu]}]);
  }
 }, []);

 for (var i = 0; i < arrayAgrupado.length; i++) {
  //cada loop desse for é um objeto com as perguntas agrupadas
  console.log(arrayAgrupado[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Jonas, meu amigo, funcionou perfeitamente, Muito agradecido!!!!